# Getting an express app working online

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am new to expressjs and am trying to get my express application (done with the express generator) working on my website, I currently uploaded the directory which is is contained in like so..

```
http://www.example.com/express-app-here
```

so I could see it working online. However, when I navigate to where the App is, I seem to only get the directory structure, and express isn't routing me to the appropriate place like it is when I go to localhost:3000.

I take it this has something to do with the fact that express isn't executing my application? Locally,

```
npm start
```

needs to be run on the console in order to get it to run, is there some kind of log I need to execute this command in? Or something I need to change in the app.js or /bin directory?

Comment: Are you starting the server using port 80? Have you set `+x` permissions to `bin/www`?

Comment: Yes, Nodejs needs to be constantly running to serve your website. Is your remote web server running Apache? If so then I'm guessing it's hounding all the port 80's and you'll need to tell Nodejs to listen on another port.

Comment: In my opinion, the biggest problem is that you need nodejs to be installed and running on your server. If this is only an apache/PHP server, you can't use node. If you can connect to it, and have sufficient rights to install node and execute it, you will be able to install your app (don't forget npm install) and run it.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments, you need to have nodejs installed on your server. It's not as simple as just copying the node app directory over to the server.

You will have to install node and npm on the server, and then run your app from the server, probably using `npm start` like you were doing on your local machine.

From there, you will want to go into your app code and make sure a route exists for /express-app-here unless you want www.example.com:3000 to take you directly to the express app.

Answer (score -1):

Basically do it like this:`

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');


var app = express();


var server = http.createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || config.webServer.port || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server running');
    console.log(port);
    console.log(server);
});

exports.module = exports = app;
```

save it app.js

Go to path via cmd. Now run:-

1)npm install express
2)npm install http

3)node app.js

Will be enough to run express server

Comment: They already have a working Express app, the issue has to do with _hosting_ that app on a (presumably) shared hosting platform.